# Ubuntu on Android?

Tags: command-line, android

I want to install Ubuntu on android via Ubuntu CLI.
I have Mobile A910.
I just want to know that if I install Ubuntu in android, and if it will not installed properly or not working properly then could I have any way to come back on android?
after Ubuntu installation, could i have my android platform? or will it be ruined? after Ubuntu installation if I didn't find it useful or something else, could I have any way to reinstall my android version? will my android safe or not?

Comment: Ubuntu on android is as far as I know no longer under active development. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_for_Android.

Comment: They wrote that ubuntu and android can run at a time, so how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer you questions:

".....could I have any way to come back on android?" :

You can [re-install](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/ubuntu-for-devices/reinstalling-android/) the android image **if** you indeed have one backed up or downloaded from somewhere.

"..could i have my android platform":

If you install Ubuntu touch, you will lose android and if you re-install android, it will remove Ubuntu.

Be warned that your device is not in the list of [supported devices](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices).

Comment: i have android 4.2. Can I install Ubuntu touch in it?